# How to include external js if exists, else do nothing (ignore)?

Tags: jquery

I have pieced together a jQuery snippet using an AJAX call to call an external file, which works just great as shown:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "http://www.domain.com/external.js",
   dataType: "script"
});
```

I only need (to create) the external file under certain conditions, but if it is not present, I get a 404 error in the browser console. I want it to do absolutely nothing (ignore) if the file is not present.

The closest related post I found is [How to include external html if exists, else do nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863668/how-to-include-external-html-if-exists-else-do-nothing) but it doesn't do nothing, it runs another function:

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/external.js",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "script"
    success: function(html){
        $('#test').html(html);
    }
  });
});
```

QUESTION: How would I go about ignoring any warnings if the file is NOT present, but run the file if it is?

Could I just do this?

```
jQuery(function() {
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/external.js",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "script"
    success: ;
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT RESPONSE TO LANCE:

Because I didn't know about it! Wow, is it really that easy? Like this?

```
try { 
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://www.domain.com/external.js",
    dataType: "script"
  });
}
catch(e){
  /* MOVE ALONG */      
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Comment: Cool, except it didn’t work. http://bit.ly/1G8NLnn     What am I missing? Do I have to do a conditional for all types of errors? Is this a "GET" error?

Comment: A little more error detail, in case it helps: http://bit.ly/1G8PPM7

Comment: Boy, I don't know.  That should trap the errors.

Comment: Lance, thanks so much for your guidance. So, your answer is spot on, and at least corrected the 404 error. As far as the red "GET" error, here's why that is present, and why it can't be made to go away: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481598/prevent-unhandled-jquery-ajax-error

Comment: Okay, great.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just using try/catch?

```
try{
    /* stuff I want to do */
}catch(e){
    /* Don't display any error.  Just move along.  Nothing to see here.
}
```